# Finding a polynomial that satisifes $p(x) = a, p'(x)=b, p''(x) =c$ for fixed $x$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Given an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and an finite list of numbers of length $n$, $(a_0,a_1, a_2, \dots,  a_{n-1})$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, would we always be able to come up with a polynomial $p(x)$ of $n$ degree, such that $p(x_0) = a_0$, $p'(x_0) = a_1$,  $p''(x_0) = a_2$ etc.?

If so, what is the general method of solving this? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Does this hold if we have a infinite list?

Comment: Let $p_0(y)=p(y+x)$ then expand $p_0(0)$ and all $p_0$'s derivatives in terms of powers of $y$ , equate to $a_k$ -- there will be a system of linear equations. Found $p_0$ it's easy finding $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
\begin{align*}
 p(x) = a_0 + a_1(x - x_0) + a_2\frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2!} + \dotsb
  + a_n\frac{(x - x_0)^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
works.

The way you can get to this is very similar to the way Taylor series are often introduced - you guess a general polynomial form like
\begin{align*}
 p(x) = b_0 + b_1(x - x_0) + b_2(x - x_0)^2 + \dotsb
  + b_n(x - x_0)^n
\end{align*}
and then you can determine the coefficients by differentiating and evaluating at $x_0$.